# Geom bar - dodging a population consisting of two different variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I want to make a plot that would show distribution (histogram) of a population, consisting of Females and Males onto one `geom_bar` with regard to Age.

It would be great if it looked something like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DPZ3.png]

This is my data:

```
> head(Oriflame)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Age   Females Males
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 14-20   11655  1014
2 20-25   23977  2372
3 25-30   22685  2243
4 30-40   42855  4761
5 40-50   32848  3649
6 50-60   18295  2261
7 60-70   11868  1467
8 70+     5198   778
```

So, basically, I created two following plots:

```
ggplot(Oriflame, aes(x=Oriflame$Age, y=Oriflame$Females)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")

ggplot(Oriflame, aes(x=Oriflame$Age, y=Oriflame$Males)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

And all I wish to do is to merge/overlap them onto one plot, with a fill/colour distinction of Females and Males. But I can't figure out how to dodge them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is going to be relatively easy: you convert the data from a wide format to a long format:

```
df <- reshape2::melt(Oriflame)
```

And set the fill in your plot to `variable`, which is now encoding the sex. You then use the `position = "dodge"`  in the `geom_col()`, which is shorthand for `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(Age, value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, you literally saved me hours of frustrating work and made my day! Have a nice weekend <3